# Get suppliers that doesn't belong to a category in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a query where I need to show all the Suppliers from the Suppliers table  that doesn't have products from category 1 (Products.CategoryID = 1). Whenever I run it it always gives an error.

[image: table views]

```
Select SupplierID From Suppliers su
where SupplierID NOT IN
(select distinct SupplierID from Products 
where SupplierID in 
(select SupplierID from Products where CategoryID=1)
```

Side question: How do I get these results but with suppliers that has products from cat. 6 ? (So none from cat1 but does have from cat6).

Comment: You need to tell us the error. You also need to provide sample data and expected results. And please only ask one question per question. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: @DaleK the answer below helped fixing the query and getting the results. Have you an idea of my sidequestion? thx in advance

Comment: @DaleK ok thank you for the feedback, I understand your point. I must say that Im a beginner and new here so any advice is welcome like you just said. Will post my other question on a new question. But the thing is i have a limit of questions, so How can I ask more :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using sub-selects, try to use set based operations like `join`s or `exists`.  One option for your situation is below, though there are several ways to achieve what you are looking to do.  Which one is best will depend on your data:

```
select su.SupplierID
From Suppliers as su
where not exists(select null -- The only check here is for a record, so you can select any value and it won't change the functionality
                 from Products as p
                 where su.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
                   and p.CategoryID = 1
                )
```

Comment: Dave, this is exacly what i'm looking for, thank you! Side-question : do you know how i get these results but with suppliers that has products from cat. 6 ? (So none from cat1 but does have from cat6)

Comment: @iamdave . . . "set operations" usually refers to `union`/`intersect`/`minus` (as you can see in the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Although these can be used to answer the question, that is not the approach the answer takes.