# Query to find certain productgroups from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a query where I need to show all the Suppliers from the Suppliers table that doesn't have products from category 1 (Products.CategoryID = 1) but does have products from category 4(Products.CategoryID = 4). Below is what I have but to only show the products not from category 1. I don't know how to include the products from category 6

Thank you for considering an answer on this question.

[image: table views]

```
select su.SupplierID, su.CompanyName
From Suppliers as su
where not exists
(select null
from Products as pr
where su.SupplierID = pr.SupplierID
and p.CategoryID = 1)
```

Comment: I'm very curious that you are using the same scheme as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66813627/get-suppliers-that-doesnt-belong-to-a-category-in-another-table) are you students together?

Comment: @DaleK No I just can't put another question on my Main account so I use this instead..

Comment: Why can't you add another question on your main account? Do you have a question ban? If so its a breach of the TOC to create another account.

Comment: I'm not banned, i just have a limit somehow so I can't ask further questions. I have to wait a day as it said

Comment: That a short term question ban... there will be a reason for it... you're not supposed to try and work around it by creating a duplicate account. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry for that.. I have to formulate my questions and have all the details.. I'm working on that. I can't be perfect from the start I know that but i will do my best for future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need exists for included categories and not exists for excluded. You can use IN for multiple categories.

```
SELECT su.SupplierID
        ,su.CompanyName
    FROM Suppliers AS su
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Products AS pr
            WHERE su.SupplierID = pr.SupplierID
                AND p.CategoryID IN (4,6)
            )
         AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Products AS pr
            WHERE su.SupplierID = pr.SupplierID
                AND p.CategoryID = 1
            )
```

Comment: As a comment: For SQL server using first EXISTS and after NOT EXISTS performs better and produces different plans

Comment: thank you for the good explanation. It's clear for me :)

Comment: You are welcome. The other peer solution is also very good, maybe better in performance. I would suggest to try to understand it

Comment: Yeah works fine as well but I prefer using this statement. It sticks better in my head so :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

> I need to show all the Suppliers from the Suppliers table that doesn't have products from category 1 (Products.CategoryID = 1) but does have products from category 4(Products.CategoryID = 4).

You can use aggregation:

```
select p.supplierID
from products p
where p.categoryID in (1, 4)
group by p.supplierID
having min(p.categoryID) = max(p.categoryID) and
      min(p.categoryID) = 4;
```

If you want to bring in other information about the supplier (apart from `supplierID`), you can use `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, or `IN`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But can you explain how you get into this?

"having min(p.categoryID) = max(p.categoryID) and
      min(p.categoryID) = 4;" 

What happens if you use this part of the statement?

Comment: I think for the case of 2 categories you can omit min(p.categoryID) = max(p.categoryID)

Comment: @niktrs . . . Yes, but that depends on the ordering of the two values and which the OP wants to keep.  I prefer to make the code safer for changing the values.

Comment: @BeginnerCoderW . . . That checks that there is only one value for `categoryID` (after filtering) per `SupplierId` and that the value is `4`.  That is exactly what the question is asking for.